# How to remove whitespace in mesh plot?

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The plot results in a white space which I need to remove.

[image: the output plot with unwanted white space]

```
clc
clear all

x = -60:.5:150;
y = -60:.5:150;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = (90-X) + (120-Y);
fileIDAngles = fopen('E:\Capstone\Simple_Neural_1\IO Files\gena.txt','r');
angle1 = fscanf(fileIDAngles,'%f');
fileIDAngles = fopen('E:\Capstone\Simple_Neural_1\IO Files\genb.txt','r');
angle2 = fscanf(fileIDAngles,'%f');
fclose(fileIDAngles);
ans =  (90-angle1) + (120-angle2);

hold on
mesh(X,Y,Z);
plot3(angle1,angle2,ans,'-o','LineWidth',1.1,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],'MarkerSize',4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your axis mins and maxes (add this line to the end of your code):

```
axis([min(x) max(x) min(y) max(y)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`axis tight`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#bul_eox-1) to bound the window within only non-zero areas of your data.  This way you don't have to explicitly use `min` and/or `max` as `axis tight` does this for you internally. As with the other answer, place `axis tight` at the end of your code.